# Reading a rotary encoder using a microcontroller and converting to Serial TTL?

Tags: microcontroller, encoder, rotary, position-sensor

I have an incremental rotary encoder ([Bournes-EMS22Q](https://www.bourns.com/docs/product-datasheets/EMS22Q.pdf)) that I would like to have available on a wired network via RJ45 or via serial TTL (we have a serial-to-ethernet converter we can use Netburner SBL2E). This seems like a fairly simple problem however the more I look into it the more complex it gets, there doesn't seem to be an off-the-shelf solution and it looks like I'll have to make something myself.

Has anyone come across this problem before? How can I get from the encoder output (5 pin) to serial/ethernet?

I'm now looking at a chip-level solution using this [32-bit Quaderature Counter](https://www.usdigital.com/products/accessories/interfaces/LS7366R-S) which gives me an SPI output but how do I go from SPI in this case to serial TTL/Ethernet? Will I need to use a microcontroller?

Is there a magical hardware component that I'm missing? Any recommendations on how to solve this problem greatly appreciated.

Comment: your question has nothing to do with IOT

Comment: I guess.... but I need to be able to access its output over a network

Comment: it seems to me that your question is about using a microcontroller to read the signals from the rotary encoder ... what you do with the data afterwards is a separate issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a microcontroller and custom firmware to read and interpret the encoder then transmit the message over serial. In essence, you have to do it manually. No magic pre-packaged solution.

If unfamiliar with microcontrollers, you can try a PICAXE or Arduino.

Comment: Thanks, I've been going crazy trying to find a prepackaged solution. Looks like I'll need to bite the bullet and get my hands dirty.